# How can I put legend of pie chart by google charts in a new line?

Tags: css, google-visualization

I used Google Charts to generate two pie charts in the same line (see the screenshot). But when the screen width updates, the legend goes beyond the screen, have to use the scrollbar.

I was wondering if there is a way that I can put the two legends beneath the pie charts and move Build: xxxx information right above the charts

[image]

Comment: chart elements are drawn using _svg_ -- each with its own _x / y_ coordinate. you would need to change these coordinates when the chart's `'ready'` event fires...